# Codeigniter - cropped image turns black

Tags: codeigniter

When I crop an image it turns completely black?? Why??

```
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/uploads/original/'; $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';

    $this->load->library('upload'); $this->upload->initialize($config);   


    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());    $this->load->view('submit', $error); } else {    $data['upload_data'] = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());    $file_name
    = $this->upload->file_name;

       list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/uploads/original/'.$file_name);

       // create small size    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';    $config['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/uploads/original/'.$file_name; $config['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/uploads/small/'.$file_name; $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;    $config['width'] = 181;    $config['height'] = 115;    $config['master_dim'] = 'width';

       $this->load->library('image_lib');  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

       if($image_width >= $config['width'] AND $image_height >= $config['height'])    {
          if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
          {
             echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
          } else {
             if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/uploads/small/'.$file_name))

             {
                list($image_width, $image_height) = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/uploads/small/'.$file_name);
                if($image_height > '115')
                { 
               $config['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/uploads/small/'.$file_name;
               $y_axis = $image_height - 115;
               $config['y_axis'] = $y_axis;
               $config['x_axis'] = 181;
               $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
               if (!$this->image_lib->crop())
                   {
                      echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                   } else {
                      echo "cropped";    
               }
             }
          }    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe CI uses the standard PHP GD module. Previously I've found that if the image you're using is slightly corrupt it will still display normally but once you resize you simply get a black box.

Have you tried using any other images? Images of different types (png/jpg/etc)?

Comment: Yes I have and still the same result :( I was going to use image-magick but from what I've read it needs to be installed or something?

Comment: Yes, the image-magick library needs to be installed but it's quite simple (there are lots of tutorials to help) and it's easier to use. I suggest giving it a try.

Comment: Whoo, actually got it working with GD2 - just wondering if it is possible to make it crop from both top and bottom rather than just top?

Comment: Image Magic also creates solid-black images randomly when resizing, etc (how I found this question), so I would not recommend it until they get the bugs worked out.